# Is there library of git for android

Tags: java, android, git

I wanted to make an app that uses git as its backend and does something like pull/fetch/ etc by just pressing button on android. Then all the information about the repo is displayed in the listview. I am able to create the listview but I am searching for the library that could help to do the git part. Is there any thing like this that anyone knows? or It could be java too I guess

eg

When a open-repo button is pressed it pulls info from the repo and displays in the listview

ps :- Further search gave me [JGit](http://eclipse.org/jgit/download/)  but I am not sure whether I am looking for this or not. Let you guys know if I find something.

Comment: Are you interested in the actual content of the repo? If not, you could consider a server-side application that does the git interaction. Then you could ask the server to do the commands, like git status or pull/fetch etc, and return the result in a more mobile friendly format.

Comment: you are right Paaske .. I went with your Idea .. thanks you so much for the response. I am using Jsch for the ssh and will do as you said from there

Comment: I'm glad to help! I'll add my comment as an answer, which you can accept :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in my comment;

Are you interested in the actual content of the repo? If not, you could consider a server-side application that does the git interaction. Then you could ask the server to do the commands, like git status or pull/fetch etc, and return the result in a more mobile friendly format.

Best of luck!

Comment: I was able to successfully implemented it, I ran the ssh connection in other thread and send the data to main UI thread to display, works as I wanted. Once again thank you x 200